# Magento - Navigation.phtml overrides not working

Tags: magento, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in the middle of developing a **bootstrap theme**, and I'm trying to modify the classes assigned to the drop menus / parents, but I'm not having much luck.

Any changes I make do not show on the frontend - I have flushed the cache, signed in/out, and I have even tried editing the actual core file but nothing is working.

I have  made a copy of `navigation.phtml` to `local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.phtml` and that is still not working.

Is there something I have missed along the way? I'm not quite sure what to do.

Comment: if you dont know magento then why bother mate? Anyone reading the title that knows about magento devolopment will know what im talking about ^^

Comment: @Andy Cresswell check the permissions on the file. It should be 644 for Magneto to work correctly. Also, what exactly are you attempting to edit?

Comment: hey mate,

Im trying to add dropdown-menu / dropdown  bootstrap class's the navigation menu as at current trying to use pre set bootstrap class's its not working ;)

Comment: i mean, am i missing something? I am trying to edit the correct file aye?

Instead of 'parent class' i need it to be 'dropdown-menu'

   if ($hasActiveChildren) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

this is the one line im trying to edit to see if changes are carried through.

Comment: Is there anyone to add data-toggle="dropdown" via jquery to each link?

Comment: @AndyCresswell as  I promised, deleting my comment and reversing my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of editing core files i decided to do it via jQuery instead...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.parent').addClass('dropdown');
jQuery('a.level-top').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
jQuery('li.parent ul').addClass('dropdown-menu');
jQuery('li.level1 ul').wrap('<li class="dropdown-submenu" />');


jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

I added the class's required via jQuery and used .wrap to wrap the dropdown-submenu around

The second part is to change from open submenu on click to open sub menu on hover..

Everything is working now and have the required classes needed to build a bootstrap multilevel dropdown in magento..

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that, As far as I know, There is no `Navigation.phtml` in `code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/`. It is `Navigation.php` Instead(Magento 1.7.x).

Secondly It is better to create a separate module if you need to override anything from core modules. Because if you are creating an exact copy in `local`, It may not work after an update.

If you are trying to create a dropdown menu, what you need to edit `app/design/frontend/base/default/` files creating a copy in `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/` folder.

The top menu lies in `app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/navigation/top.phtml`. For detailed seeing, switch on template path hints in `System>Configuration>Developer>Debug`.

Comment: Hi mate,

Im aware how to edit all the Design / html / php files (app/design/frontend)

what i need to do is edit the actual structure of the menu itself.. for example... For all .parent i need to add dropdownmenu

for every .parent .parent i need to add dropdown-submenu this way all default bootstrap css class's will work as default..

Comment: you are correct, navigation.phtml is infact a .php file, anyway it still doesnt work (any changes made to core or local)

looks like its time to start learning php and writing magento plug ins..

Comment: also, i been working with magento for a a while, ur points above are basic magento stuff ^^

What i need to do is edit core structure ;) i figured it with jqueyr for now, but will learn how to do it on the backend level. i will be releasing my theme to the public so its important everything is perfect and upgrade proof :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want convert Magento 1.7.x to Bootstrap navigation cope topmenu.phtml into your theme:

*magento/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml*

add jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#nav").magentoBootstrapNavigation();
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

and you get something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @see Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
 */
?>
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#nav").magentoBootstrapNavigation();
        });
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Then add js file via local.xml

```
<!-- jQuery scripts -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/jquery-scripts/magento-to-bootstrap-navigation.js</script></action>
```

Create js file:

*magento/skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/js/jquery-scripts/magento-to-bootstrap-navigation.js*

Open magento-to-bootstrap-navigation.js end paste:

```
/*
* Convert default Magento navigation to Bootstrap navigation
 */
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.magentoBootstrapNavigation = function() {

        var menu = function(){
            var nav = $(this);

            nav.find(".parent")
                .addClass("dropdown")
                .children("a").addClass("dropdown-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown").append( ' <b class="caret"></b>')
                .next().addClass("dropdown-menu");
        };

        return this.each(menu);

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Thats all.

PS: You can get problem with self hide for .btn-group.
I fix that problem by editing core Bootstrap dropdown.js file:

*path_to_your_bootstrap/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js*

Open and find line:

```
$parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown')
```

and replace with:

```
//$parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown')
$parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown').show()
```

Have a nice day.